# two for statements go into print a loop

Tags: python

I have a program to print out a scorebord or ranking list and at this moment I have a list with team name, score and played games but I also want to print out the position with `range()`.
The code goes as follows:

```
for a in rankinglist:
    for pos in range(1, 33):
        print(format(pos) +
          format(a.name, '>18') +
          format(str(a.games), '>7') +
          format(str(a.score), '>11'))
```

`rankinglist` is the list of teams and `pos` should be a range from 1 to 32.
My intention was to print out this:

```
1             team1      0          0
2             team2      0          0
3             team3      0          0
4             team4      0          0
5             team5      0          0
6             team6      0          0
7             team7      0          0
8             team8      0          0
9             team9      0          0
10            team10     0          0
...
```

but instead I get loop which prints out every team 32 times.

```
1             team1      0          0
2             team1      0          0
3             team1      0          0
4             team1      0          0
5             team1      0          0
6             team1      0          0
7             team1      0          0
8             team1      0          0
9             team1      0          0
10            team1      0          0
11            team1      0          0
12            team1      0          0
13            team1      0          0
14            team1      0          0
15            team1      0          0
16            team1      0          0
17            team1      0          0
18            team1      0          0
19            team1      0          0
20            team1      0          0
21            team1      0          0
22            team1      0          0
23            team1      0          0
24            team1      0          0
25            team1      0          0
26            team1      0          0
27            team1      0          0
28            team1      0          0
29            team1      0          0
30            team1      0          0
31            team1      0          0
32            team1      0          0
```

Anyone knows a way to solve this?

Comment: You don't need 2 `for` loops , in second for loop you just iterate over `pos` and `a` does not change , that's because just `team1` prints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
for pos, a in enumerate(rankinglist, 1):
    print(format(pos) +
      format(a.name, '>18') +
      format(str(a.games), '>7') +
      format(str(a.score), '>11'))
```

Comment: I agree that this would be the right way. Just note that the question asked for indexes beginning from 1, so you'd need `enumerate(rankinglist, 1)`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I edited the response. Thanks! =)